# R: how to write a function that samples given the probability

Tags: r, sapply

I wrote a function

```
p = c(0.4, 0.6)
myfun = function(p){
    sample(1:2, 1, replace = TRUE, prob = p)
}
```

And I want to repeat this 5 times.

```
sapply(1:5, myfun)
```

But this gives me an error

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :    incorrect
>   number of probabilities

Comment: maybe you want to sample from 1:2 ? Otherwise prob must be of length 10...

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. I want to sample from 1:2, but I still get the same error.

Comment: `replicate(5, sample(2, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.6)))`

Comment: p is not used in your case. Sapply will feed 1 to 5 to myfun every time.

Comment: @Indicator. So if I want to use sapply to to this, I tried sapply(1:5, myfun(p)) but that doesn't sem to work either.

Comment: In the form of sapply(x,y) , y must be a function, but myfun(p) is a value not a function. Richard's answer tells that you can use replicate other than sapply to repeatedly call a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your function with `replicate`.

```
myfun <- function(x, p, n, replace = TRUE) {
    m <- replicate(n, sample(x, replace = replace, prob = p))
    if(n == 1) c(m) else m
}
myfun(2, c(0.4, 0.6), 5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2    1    2
myfun(2, c(0.4, 0.6), 1)
# [1] 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sample` function to sample 5 values.

```
p <- c(0.4, 0.6)
sample(1:2, 5, replace = TRUE, prob = p)
# [1] 2 2 2 2 1
```